# Changing port when running Jetty using jetty-runner

Tags: java, command-line, jetty

I'm executing the following command line:

```
java -jar C:\WorkArea\jetty-runner.jar c:\name.war --port 9090
```

I'm expecting it to run on port 9090 but it keeps on running using port 8080 which is the default. 
What am I missing? 
When running through eclipse itself, it is using 8888 so it's not taking this info from there, where/how else can I control the port?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Using_Jetty_Runner) of the Jetty Runner suggests that the port option should be passed before the WAR file:

```
java -jar C:\WorkArea\jetty-runner.jar --port 9090 c:\name.war
```

Comment: It does show it before the WAR but I didn't think it was a recommendation as it is not emphasized anywhere... oh well... thank you for the quick response.